# C# list of past DateTimes

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a method that returns the past *x* days and it currently does the following:

```
var dates = new List<DateTime>();

for (int i = 0; i < numDays; i++)
{
    dates.Add(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-i));
}

return dates;
```

I feel like there should be a more compact way of doing this, perhaps using LINQ.  Suggestions?  Also, if I do keep it the way I have it, is `DateTime.Today` such that this would be more efficient if I stored it in a variable outside the loop and then called `AddDays` on that value within the loop?

**Edit:**  LINQ uses lazy evaluation, right?  I'm getting crazy images in my head:

```
return DateTime.AllDaysInTheHistoryOfTimeEver.Where(day =>
    day.BeforeOrOn(DateTime.Today) &&
    day.After(DateTime.Today.AddDays(-numDays))
);
```

Comment: LOL, AllDaysInTheHistoryOfTimeEver!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var start = DateTime.Today;
var days = Enumerable.Range(0, numDays).Select(i => start.AddDays(-i)).ToList();
```

Capturing `start` first avoids a corner-case of running it at around midnight.

Comment: Interesting solution. in one line : var qry = Enumerable.Range(0, numDays).Select(i => DateTime.Today.AddDays(-i)).ToList();

Comment: @Atomiton - now run it *just before* midnight ;-p

Comment: @Marc:  I'm using your solution and I captured `DateTime.Today` as you did, but can you explain/give a link as to why this fixes a corner case?  Something with closures?

Comment: @Sarah - if the code ran through a few iterations just before midnight and then finished up after midnight, the value of DateTime.Today would change during the iteration! This would produce a duplicate value in the days collection.

Comment: @Marc. Wow! Great point! Silly computers, not thinking for themselves. :-)

Answer (score 1):

maybe not linq but you can do it with an iterator, not sure about your exact requirements (i.e. numDays) but the below will get you the last 10 days.

```
var dates = GetDates(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10),DateTime.Now);

 public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetDates(DateTime StartingDate, DateTime EndingDate)
        {
            while (StartingDate <= EndingDate)
            {
                yield return StartingDate;
                StartingDate = StartingDate.AddDays(1);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I like your suggestion of using `yield`.  I'll check and see how my method is being used and see if an iterator would make more sense.

Answer (score 1):

Marc's answer provides a more persuasive reason to capture the start time, but reflector is one of my guilty pleasures, so I checked and discovered that capturing the start time would also be more efficient (though ... well, you know, unlikely to ever matter, etc..)

When you call `DateTime.Today`, it returns `UtcNow.ToLocalTime()` which adds a bit more processing overhead compared to using a date that's already `DateTimeKind.Local`:

```
public virtual DateTime ToLocalTime(DateTime time)
{
    if (time.Kind == DateTimeKind.Local)
    {
        return time;
    }
    bool isAmbiguousLocalDst = false;
    long utcOffsetFromUniversalTime = ((CurrentSystemTimeZone) CurrentTimeZone).GetUtcOffsetFromUniversalTime(time, ref isAmbiguousLocalDst);
    return new DateTime(time.Ticks + utcOffsetFromUniversalTime, DateTimeKind.Local, isAmbiguousLocalDst);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the background info.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of collecting the values in a list you can return an IEnumerator or IEnumerable and use the yield keyword.

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx) article

Comment: I don't want to read MSDN articles. Can you show an example of code to do this?

Comment: @DOK:  Pharabus' answer uses `yield`:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134893/c-list-of-past-datetimes/2134956#2134956